# How to correctly send data/call module from another module in VIPER (swift)?

Tags: swift, navigation, viper-architecture

Router contains a link to navigation controller which contains stacked 1,2,3 view controllers (from 1,2,3 modules). Now module 3 commands router `navigationController.popToRoot` and should call `someFunc()` from module1.

If it is usual project I call `popToRoot`, get the root view controller and call `someFunc()` directly. But how to do it with VIPER architecture correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest two ways:

**1) Implement a Coordinator.** Let the Coordinator know that there's a `navigationController`, and make it accessible by every `Router`, presumably bidirectional. Then, Coordinator can call Module1's method when Module3 is done.

**2) Implement a Notification System.** Just keep calling `popToRoot` in Module3's `Router`, and send a notification to the `NotificationCenter`. Since Module1 will still be alive (since they are stacked), it can act/react accordingly.

*I'd vote for the first option though, having a Coordinator in VIPER immensely (and subjectively) helps with the routing.*